# Generate list from treeitem using c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

we have a list of the class

```
public class DummyClass
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int LevelNo { get; set; }
        public List<DummyClass> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

we want to add this list to another list with class.

```
public class FragmentLevel
{
 public int currentLevelNo { get; set; }
 public int ParentLevelNo { get; set; }
 public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

we need the result like

```
var list = new List<FragmentLevel>
            {
              new FragmentLevel{ id = 1, text = "Root" },
              new FragmentLevel{ id = 2, parent= 1, text = "Node-1.1" },
              new FragmentLevel{ id = 3, parent= 2, text = "Node-1.1.1" }
            };
```

For getting result we are doing like

```
 for (int i = 0; i < DummyClassList.Count; i++)
                    {

                        list.Add(new FragmentLevel
                        {
                            currentLevelNo = DummyClassList[i].LevelNo,
                            Text = DummyClassList[i].Text,
                        });
                        do
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < DummyClassList[i].Children.Count; j++)
                            {
                                list1.Add(new FragmentLevel
                                {
                                   LevelNo = DummyClassList[i].Children[j].LevelNo,
                                   Text = DummyClassList[i].Children[j].Text,
                                });
                            }

                        } while (DummyClassList[i].Children[i].Children != null);
                    }
```

But this will give wrong result. How we can get the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way of filling the fragments recursively,

```
  private static void FillFragments(List<DummyClass> DummyClassList, List<FragmentLevel> list)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < DummyClassList.Count; i++)
        {
            list.Add(new FragmentLevel
            {
                currentLevelNo = DummyClassList[i].LevelNo,
                Text = DummyClassList[i].Text,
            });

            if (DummyClassList[i].Children != null && DummyClassList[i].Children.Count > 0)
            {
                FillFragments(DummyClassList[i].Children, list);
            }
        }
    }
```

and the main method would look like this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var DummyClassList = new List<DummyClass>
        {
            new DummyClass
            {
                Children = new List<DummyClass>
                {
                    new DummyClass{
                        Children = null,
                        LevelNo=2,
                        Text = "two"
                    }
                },
            LevelNo = 1,
            Text = "one"
            }
        };

        var list = new List<FragmentLevel>();


        FillFragments(DummyClassList, list);

    }
```